# How do I safely replicate data to another data center

Tags: database, microservices, database-replication, distributed-system

So I have my simple chat system that looks like this. So a user connects to API gateway via websocket. Whenever he sends the message to another user it will send a message to the message broker. Chat service then will have a consumer that notify the message to the target user (if he's connected to the same node) before saving it to the database for chat history.

The problem is, I want to be able scale by adding more nodes on different data centers so I wonder how could new node safely replicate data from the existing node.

[image]

when it comes to large scale distributed systems I only know some basic concepts such as single-leader replication, multi-leader replication. So in this case I don't how could I replicate the chat history from mongdb to the new node.

I'm considering  blocking all the request during the replication process and I will manually copy the data from mongodb to the new data centers and start accepting request again. The new node on the data center then consumes the message from the message broker and automatically update its own database, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach ? there maybe better approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from looking into capabilities provided by MongoDb for geographical replication:

- [Deploy a Geographically Redundant Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-geographically-distributed-replica-set/)
- [Replica Sets Distributed Across Two or More Data Centers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/)
- [Add Members to a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/tutorial/expand-replica-set/)

Especially check the section about ability to use snapshots (it can greatly decrease the downtime for new node).

Another approach (which though might not be applicable to your current system) - use some kind of persisted distributed log and reread for every new node.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with a replication solution. In my opinion, that would be too much data flowing around.

Let me give an example: three nodes and two users; even if users are clearly connected to one or two servers, the data itself is being replicated to every node. Seems like a waste.

I would approach to the problem by decoupling message delivery from chat history management.

Message delivery requires a "registry" to map users to nodes they are connected to. When a user connects to a node, the very first thing is to update the registry with "User X is on Node Y". So if someone wants to reach to User X, the system knows how to route the message to their current node.

The chat history service would be completely decoupled from the message delivery. When a message is being send, the message is sent to a queue to be stored in the data layer. And the history may be read when needed from the data layer.

The point of decoupled approach is to allow every component be independently scalable.